# which data types help in timer behavior flow in python

Tags: python, algorithm, timer

```
for MaxTime:
    run function1 for timeout 10 secs
    after timeout 10 sec ,again
    run function1 for timeout 10 secs
    after timeout 10 sec , again
    run function1 for timeout 10 secs
    ...
    (do it untill MaxTime is reached )
```

which modules below can be used/helpful  ?

```
sched.scheduler
```

or

```
threading.timer
```

mix of two above?

could you point algo for this ?

function1 is just a logging code which logs to a txt file.
every time i should run the same function ; function1
or just for simplicity ..assume function1 as block of code

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Can you provide more context?

Comment: i am sorry for presenting the problem vaguely. here is it :

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like [`pygame.time.Clock()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)?

Execute `function1()` every 10 seconds until 100 seconds pass:

```
import logging
import pygame

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
def function1():
    logging.warning("write logs")

fps = .1      # call function1() every 10 seconds
maxtime = 100 # finish in 100 seconds

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
for _ in range(int(maxtime*fps + .5)):
    function1()
    clock.tick(fps) # at most `fps` function1() calls per second
```

#### Output

```
11:44:05 write logs
11:44:15 write logs
11:44:25 write logs
11:44:35 write logs
11:44:45 write logs
11:44:55 write logs
11:45:05 write logs
11:45:15 write logs
11:45:25 write logs
11:45:35 write logs
```

Similar thing implemented using `threading.Timer()`:

```
import logging
from time import time as timer
from threading import Timer

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%H:%M:%S')

def function1(interval, maxtime):
    logging.warning('write logs')
    if timer() < maxtime:
        Timer(interval, function1, (interval, maxtime)).start()

function1(10, timer()+100)
```

Note: each `Timer()` spawns a new thread.

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/LmlBi)

```
09:06:31 write logs
09:06:41 write logs
09:06:51 write logs
09:07:01 write logs
09:07:11 write logs
09:07:21 write logs
09:07:31 write logs
09:07:41 write logs
09:07:51 write logs
09:08:01 write logs
09:08:11 write logs
```

Comment: i guess it is not apt for my requirement

Comment: @namus: I've added `threading.Timer()` variant for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`glib.timeout_add(interval, callback, ...)`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--timeout-add). It will execute `callback` every `interval` milliseconds until the callback returns `False`.

To make sure that the callback is no longer executed after `MaxTime`, you can just pass the time it was first executed like this:

```
import gtk, glib
import time

def callback(max_time, start_time):
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print 'Writing logs...'
    return elapsed_time < max_time


glib.timeout_add(10000, callback, 100, time.time())
gtk.main()
```

Note: `interval` is in millseconds and `max_time` in seconds (this can be changed if required)